# If we pay for a font, are we fully authorized to use it in our website?

Tags: web-fonts, font-face, font-licensing

I'm finishing a project, and I was thinking to use a font that I liked a lot, but it is paid; I don't mind to pay, because it is not very expensive, and I think it's worth it.

On the font website says, "You may use the fonts to create Web Pages" and "Bariol font can be used with @ font-face".

So I'm in doubt, if I can or not use this font in my project if I pay it, because even I pay, the people that access the website have access to the font...

So is using this font in my website allowed?

Here below I have some text using this font:

[image]

Does anyone know of a Google font similar to this?

Because of this situation, I'm already looking for a Google font, in case that is not allowed to use Bariol font. I saw open-sans, and I like it, but it is not very similar to Bariol, but as I have not much experience, I came here to ask your help.

Comment: "Bariol font can be used with @ font-face" = isn't that your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always look at what the license says. If it specifically allows use of font on webpages, then it's not your concern if other users are able to access the font file.

Comment: Many tools which use @font-face (woff files are one such) can restrict the font to the specific site it's intended for. That would mean that you don't need to worry that others can get at the font: they couldn't use it in its delivered form. But since the licence specifically allows creating webfont files, the font creator is happy whatever.

Comment: @AndrewLeach WOFF files are as easy to "extract" and use as any, regardless of "protection" :}

Comment: @thebodzio Yes; I was aware that was almost certainly the case (even though WOFF is *supposed* to impart a level of protection), although I didn't word the comment carefully enough. However my last sentence might imply it :-)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah, I just wanted to be explicit about it :}